# Can DB2REMOTE be used to point a file from another server?

Tags: db2, load, scp, db2-luw, cross-server

Using the script below, I was able to load the data to the table with local files.

`db2 load from SOME/LOCAL/File.txt of asc modified by reclen=123 method L \(1 11, 12 14\) REPLACE INTO schema.tablename`

However, I want to achieve to load the file from another server. I don't want to transfer the files from another server to db2 server so I will be able to use the command as above. Found that `DB2REMOTE` can be used for `remotefiles` in [this documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.1?topic=commands-load-using-admin-cmd), but I'm not sure how to execute it with success.

Do I need to do [this](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-catalog-storage-access) also? Because I don't have the right IAM role and don't have the credentials to do so. If I just can skip this and proceed to connect with another server only.

This is the script I'm trying with DB2REMOTE:

`db2 load from 'DB2REMOTE://centos@123.456.789.0:/folders/directory/file.txt' of asc modified by reclen=123 method L \(1 11, 12 14\) REPLACE INTO schema.tablename`

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`DB2REMOTE` is for accessing cloud object storage (e.g Amazon S3, IBM Cloud Object Storage), from some Db2 commands.

If you are not using cloud object storage, then mount the remote directory locally with appropriate permissions, and specify the local mountpoint with the Db2 load command .

You can remote mount with SSHFS or similar, when installed and properly configured. This is not programming , but instead it is administration and configuration.